# central log-server with auditdisp

Tags: linux, logging, audit, security

I want to setup a central log-server. The log-server is running with debian 6.0.6 and the audit daemon is installed in version 1.7.13-1.

The Clients are running with Red Hat 5.5 and they connect to the log-server via audispd. The connection works fine and i get all messages from each node.

My questions is: is it possible that the auditd daemon from the log server write the messages from each node in a separate file?

I try to transfer the messages via the syslog daemon, that works but i can not use tools like ausearch to analyze these log-files.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do it with rsyslog like that

```
$template DynFile,"/var/log/%HOSTNAME%/%programname%.log"
```

http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog_conf_actions.html

Comment: I try this solution and works fine but i can not use the tools like ausearch for these files.

Comment: why ? because of its format ? you can change it. check the templates in rsyslog

Comment: these are my templates in rsyslog.conf
 
      $template auditd, "/var/logClients/%HOSTNAME%-%FROMHOST-IP%/audit.log"
      $template myFor,"%msg\n"
Any idea?

Comment: maybe if you remove \n ?. Also I guess that you know that "myFor" you must use it as " *  /var/log/auditd;myFor ";  http://www.rsyslog.com/using-a-different-log-format-for-all-files/

Comment: no, you need this that every message got in a new line. Like in the audit.log